# How to make app autorunning with root privileges?

Tags: .desktop

I want to make `jetbrains-toolbox` app start with root privileges on boot. How can I do it? Config file is overwritten with default on every boot with config, which doesn't have `gksu -k -u root`. Here is the `.desktop` file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=JetBrains Toolbox
Exec= gksu -k -u root /home/odm3n/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/bin/jetbrains-toolbox %u
Icon=/home/odm3n/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/toolbox.svg
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-toolbox
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/jetbrains;
```

Comment: Why would you run the toolbox as root? That's not how it is meant to be used. It should run with regular user privileges.

Comment: @ByteCommander to tun intleji  apps with root prevelegies, cause without root they can't modify any permissions

Comment: The IDEs are not meant to be run as root either, like most GUI applications. You should really not do this and find another way. Make sure everything in your home folder is owned by your user, and when you need to modify other system files, use `sudo` for that single command. Follow the principle of least privileges.

Comment: @ByteCommander so, `sudo chown -R username username/` can solve my problem?

Comment: @ByteCommander yap, it solved all the problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there is no need to ever run the Toolbox or any of the IDEs as root. The underlying problem was that ownership of some files were already messed up (probably because you ran the IDEs as root once).

You can fix the ownership by making your user the owner of all files in your home directory again, including all of the JetBrains IDE/Toolbox files:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```